# How can I identify specifications for this possible passive speaker with subwoofer? And what are each wirings on that cable for?

Tags: audio, cables, speakers

From Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/g5aynj/can_someone_help_me_identify_the_specifications/ I tried to get specifications of a speaker. This one here is specifically for ASUS ROG GL752VW, a gaming laptop.

What was found out is that it is possibly a passive speaker, so the speakers don't have any power in it, analogue audio, apperantly. Unsure if it gets sent in digital or analogue.

Here are some images of the speaker from the Google search: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yTNl.jpg

and here is a picture of the, that was found from the Reddit post and the image is from here https://www.ebay.com/itm/ASUS-ROG-GL752V-Internal-Speaker-MT2920b/114108584582?hash=item1a9166d286:g:mQoAAOSwfiNeQgK3

[image]

From the image of the cable you can see that is uses 2x black, 1x red and 1x white wiring colors. This cable is from the speaker and later gets connected somewhere on the mainboard.

What I could also find out is that the speaker might was made from a company called VECO if, I compare the logo on the casing http://www.veco.com.cn/.

Now my question is, what do each of these colors here mean? And how do the speakers work, do they need power or not? And is it possible to determine what their specifications are, as example "2W x Stereo" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

It's more or less impossible to find out what the specs are unless they're printed on a part or you can find original information from the manufacturer.

You can make educated guesses, though; the use of red and white probably matches the standard RCA red for right, white for left audio, and the black is probably ground, and the two black wires are therefore probably ground for the channels that they are next to. Probing it with a multimeter in conductivity mode would probably show low resistance when you have a matched pair. You could then apply a signal from a headphone output (these are nice and low power) and see if you hear anything.

On the other hand, if you take it apart and find a circuit board in there, it's probably digital.

Comment: Can by the size of the speaker, be determined what specs or things it could be? Also, how are passive speakers measured in?

Answer (score 0):

It's a stereo speaker set. Red/Black is right, White/black is left. Use a multimeter to check the pairs: black may be common, but normally isn't.